# Why doesn't my if statement respond to the changes I made to the variables?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```
var count = 0;    
if(count % 2 == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < squareStorage.length; i++) {
            squareStorage[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                console.log("This is: " + i)
                console.log(count%2)
                count++;
                console.log(count);
            });
        }
    }
    
else if(count % 2 == 1) {
    console.log(count%2)
        for (let i = 0; i < squareStorage.length; i++) {
            squareStorage[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("This is (no.2): " + i)
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Those are part of my code. I wanted the variable count to change as I click on a bunch of divs which I threw into the squareStorage variable. I tried by increasing variable count whenever I click. However, my if statement somehow keeps on running, even when count % 2 is not 0.

Comment: can you add more code, where is this code located? how is it called exactly?

Comment: In the code above you will only execute the first `if` and therefore only evert run the frst events.

Comment: Well if `count` is odd the 2nd `else if` executes @Bibberty. But since as the question indicates `count` isn't odd, `var count = 0;`, I see your point

Comment: Exactly, even if we assume that code is called multiple times. count is set to 0 at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a common mistake, you need to add your events seperately and then in the event call the code.

Here is example.

```js
let count = 0;

// This method will deal with the logic on each click. 
// NOTE: we are not re-doing our events.
const processClick = () => {
    if(count%2 == 0) {
      console.log(`This is one: count ${count}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`This is two: count ${count}`);
    }
    count++;
};

// When document loads we will find all divs and add a click event.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Find all our DIV elements and add a click event to them.
  document.querySelectorAll('div')
          .forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', processClick));
});
```

```html
<div>Click</div>
<div>Click</div>
<div>Click</div>
<div>Click</div>
<div>Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten to remove the old event listeners which you can do with `removeEventListener`.

eg:

```
function myClickFunction {
 // ... do stuff for first click function
}

// when loading the 2nd click function you run this
squareStorage[i].removeEventListener('click', myClickFunction)
```

Comment: I think it is deeper than that. This code will likely only add the first events.

Comment: You're right, best to use just the 1 callback rather than switching.